# How can I make this JavaScript/CSS random animation code simpler?

Tags: javascript, css, refactoring, document.write

The JavaScript code below generates CSS to set up an animation using random values. The code is complicated and repetitive. How can this code be written more elegantly?

```
axis=["X","Y","Z"];
document.write("@keyframes tumble { "+
"12% {transform:rotate"+axis[Math.floor(Math.random()*3)]+"(-"+Math.floor(Math.random()*180)+"deg) rotate"+axis[Math.floor(Math.random()*3)]+
"("+Math.floor(Math.random()*180)+"deg) rotate"+axis[Math.floor(Math.random()*3)]+"("+Math.floor(Math.random()*180)+"deg)}"+
"32% {transform:rotate"+axis[Math.floor(Math.random()*3)]+"(-"+Math.floor(Math.random()*180)+"deg) rotate"+axis[Math.floor(Math.random()*3)]+
"("+Math.floor(Math.random()*180)+"deg) rotate"+axis[Math.floor(Math.random()*3)]+"("+Math.floor(Math.random()*180)+"deg)}"+
"50% {transform:rotate"+axis[Math.floor(Math.random()*3)]+"( "+Math.floor(Math.random()*180)+"deg) rotate"+axis[Math.floor(Math.random()*3)]+
"("+Math.floor(Math.random()*180)+"deg) rotate"+axis[Math.floor(Math.random()*3)]+"("+Math.floor(Math.random()*180)+"deg)}"+
"66% {transform:rotate"+axis[Math.floor(Math.random()*3)]+"( "+Math.floor(Math.random()*180)+"deg) rotate"+axis[Math.floor(Math.random()*3)]+
"("+Math.floor(Math.random()*180)+"deg) rotate"+axis[Math.floor(Math.random()*3)]+"("+Math.floor(Math.random()*180)+"deg)}"+
"84% {transform:rotate"+axis[Math.floor(Math.random()*3)]+"( "+Math.floor(Math.random()*180)+"deg) rotate"+axis[Math.floor(Math.random()*3)]+
"("+Math.floor(Math.random()*180)+"deg) rotate"+axis[Math.floor(Math.random()*3)]+"("+Math.floor(Math.random()*180)+"deg)}"+"}</style>");
```

Comment: For questions like these maybe you'd better off to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to work on an answer a step at a time and share with you as I go.

The first simple step is some very minor reformatting just to get the line lengths shorter and make it a little easier to see the code. In practice, I probably wouldn't worry about the line lengths at this point, but shorter lines will display better here:

```
axis = [ "X","Y","Z" ];

document.write(
    "@keyframes tumble { "+

    "12% {transform:rotate" +
    axis[Math.floor(Math.random()*3)] +
    "(-" + Math.floor(Math.random()*180) + "deg) rotate" +
    axis[Math.floor(Math.random()*3)] + 
    "(" + Math.floor(Math.random()*180) + "deg) rotate" +
    axis[Math.floor(Math.random()*3)] +
    "(" + Math.floor(Math.random()*180) + "deg)}" +

    "32% {transform:rotate" +
    axis[Math.floor(Math.random()*3)] +
    "(-" + Math.floor(Math.random()*180) + "deg) rotate" +
    axis[Math.floor(Math.random()*3)] + 
    "(" + Math.floor(Math.random()*180) + "deg) rotate" +
    axis[Math.floor(Math.random()*3)] +
    "(" + Math.floor(Math.random()*180) + "deg)}" +

    "50% {transform:rotate" +
    axis[Math.floor(Math.random()*3)] +
    "( " + Math.floor(Math.random()*180) + "deg) rotate" +
    axis[Math.floor(Math.random()*3)] + 
    "(" + Math.floor(Math.random()*180) + "deg) rotate" +
    axis[Math.floor(Math.random()*3)] +
    "(" + Math.floor(Math.random()*180) + "deg)}" +

    "66% {transform:rotate" +
    axis[Math.floor(Math.random()*3)] +
    "( " + Math.floor(Math.random()*180) + "deg) rotate" +
    axis[Math.floor(Math.random()*3)] + 
    "(" + Math.floor(Math.random()*180) + "deg) rotate" +
    axis[Math.floor(Math.random()*3)] +
    "(" + Math.floor(Math.random()*180) + "deg)}" +

    "84% {transform:rotate" +
    axis[Math.floor(Math.random()*3)] +
    "( " + Math.floor(Math.random()*180) + "deg) rotate" +
    axis[Math.floor(Math.random()*3)] + 
    "(" + Math.floor(Math.random()*180) + "deg) rotate" +
    axis[Math.floor(Math.random()*3)] +
    "(" + Math.floor(Math.random()*180) + "deg)}" +

    "}</style>"
);
```

Two items jump out right away: It looks like there is a missing `<style>` tag at the beginning of the generated code (There is a `</style>` at the end.) And there's a missing `var` on the `axis = ...` statement.

The next thing that is apparent is that these two patterns occur over and over again in the code:

```
Math.floor(Math.random()*3)

Math.floor(Math.random()*180)
```

So let's write some functions to make those simpler, and do a simple search and replace to change the existing code to use these functions:

```
// Return a random integer n in the range 0 <= n < limit
function randInt( limit ) {
    return Math.floor( Math.random() * limit );
}

// Return a random integer n in the range 0 <= n < 3
function rand3() {
    return randInt( 3 );
}

// Return a random integer n in the range 0 <= n < 180
function rand180() {
    return randInt( 180 );
}

var axis = [ "X","Y","Z" ];

// Write a <style> tag to the document with a random animation
document.write(
    "<style>@keyframes tumble { "+

    "12% {transform:rotate" +
    axis[rand3()] +
    "(-" + rand180() + "deg) rotate" +
    axis[rand3()] + 
    "(" + rand180() + "deg) rotate" +
    axis[rand3()] +
    "(" + rand180() + "deg)}" +

    "32% {transform:rotate" +
    axis[rand3()] +
    "(-" + rand180() + "deg) rotate" +
    axis[rand3()] + 
    "(" + rand180() + "deg) rotate" +
    axis[rand3()] +
    "(" + rand180() + "deg)}" +

    "50% {transform:rotate" +
    axis[rand3()] +
    "( " + rand180() + "deg) rotate" +
    axis[rand3()] + 
    "(" + rand180() + "deg) rotate" +
    axis[rand3()] +
    "(" + rand180() + "deg)}" +

    "66% {transform:rotate" +
    axis[rand3()] +
    "( " + rand180() + "deg) rotate" +
    axis[rand3()] + 
    "(" + rand180() + "deg) rotate" +
    axis[rand3()] +
    "(" + rand180() + "deg)}" +

    "84% {transform:rotate" +
    axis[rand3()] +
    "( " + rand180() + "deg) rotate" +
    axis[rand3()] + 
    "(" + rand180() + "deg) rotate" +
    axis[rand3()] +
    "(" + rand180() + "deg)}" +

    "}</style>"
);
```

As you can see, the code is already *much* simpler.

Now let's see what is the same and what is different among those five similar blocks of code. It's helpful to load these blocks into a program that can do character-by-character (intraline) diffs. I use [Araxis Merge](http://www.araxis.com/merge/) for this. [Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/) is another good choice. These are both commercial products; there are undoubtedly good free alternatives too.

Here's what Araxis Merge displays when we compare the first block with the last:

[image: Araxis Merge diff of two similar code blocks]

(If you don't like the font, don't blame Araxis; that's just my personal setting. And the narrow width with word wrap is just to make it fit in the column here.)

We can see that there are only two differences: The percentage number in the first line, and the `"(-"` vs. `"( "` in the third line. Indeed, those are the only two differences among all the blocks.

So, what we can do now is write a function that returns this snippet of code and lets us plug in those two values.

```
// Return a transform:rotate string with the specified
// percent and flag
function makeTransform( percent, flag ) {
    return (
        percent + "% {transform:rotate" +
        axis[rand3()] +
        "(" + flag + rand180() + "deg) rotate" +
        axis[rand3()] + 
        "(" + rand180() + "deg) rotate" +
        axis[rand3()] +
        "(" + rand180() + "deg)}"
        );
}
```

Now looking at that function, there are still a few things that are repeated in it. But it's really simple enough at this point; the repetition is fairly minor. Since we're at it, though, let's see how we might refactor that code a bit more:

```
// Return a random axis and degree string
function randAxisDegree( flag ) {
    return axis[rand3()] + "(" + flag + rand180() + "deg)";
}

// Return a transform:rotate string with the specified
// percent and flag
function makeTransform( percent, flag ) {
    return (
        percent + "% {transform:rotate" +
            randAxisDegree(flag) + " rotate" +
            randAxisDegree("") + " rotate" +
            randAxisDegree("") +
        "}"
    );
}
```

Of course, now we may notice that the `rand3()` and `rand180()` functions I made earlier aren't really necessary, since they are now used only one place each and don't really need to be separate functions at all.

In fact, looking back at the code, those two functions aren't really helpful even if they *are* called multiple places: `rand3()` is hardly better than `randInt(3)`, or to keep the same brevity, even rename that function as `rand()` so we can say `rand(3)` instead of `rand3()`.

I'm tempted to edit this answer to take this approach from the beginning, but let's leave it alone to show the somewhat crooked path refactoring can take. We'll remove them now though, and call `randInt()` directly from `randAxisDegree()`:

```
// Return a random axis and degree string
function randAxisDegree( flag ) {
    return axis[randInt(3)] + "(" + flag + randInt(180) + "deg)";
}
```

And now we can see how it all fits together:

```
// Return a random integer n in the range 0 <= n < limit
function randInt( limit ) {
    return Math.floor( Math.random() * limit );
}

var axis = [ "X", "Y", "Z" ];

// Return a random axis and degree string
function randAxisDegree( flag ) {
    return axis[randInt(3)] + "(" + flag + randInt(180) + "deg)";
}

// Return a transform:rotate string with the specified
// percent and flag
function makeTransform( percent, flag ) {
    return (
        percent + "% {transform:rotate" +
            randAxisDegree(flag) + " rotate" +
            randAxisDegree("") + " rotate" +
            randAxisDegree("") +
        "}"
    );
}

// Write a <style> tag to the document with a random animation
document.write(
    "<style>@keyframes tumble { " +
        makeTransform( 12, "-" ) +
        makeTransform( 32, "-" ) +
        makeTransform( 50, " " ) +
        makeTransform( 66, " " ) +
        makeTransform( 84, " " ) +
    "}</style>"
);
```

Comment: Thanks Michael, very elegant! I have been struggling to come up with something like this.

Comment: You're welcome, gaba, I'm pleased to know that was helpful. Be sure to take a look at the latest version of the answer where I continued the simplification process. The new code is nice and clean - if I do say so myself. :-)

Alas, for some reason your question was closed. That doesn't make sense to me: I thought it was a very good question. I'm just glad I had a chance to answer it before it was closed.

Comment: Great walk-through of the thought process. Leaving in the initial 'rand3' and 'rand180` is a great way to show how initial simplification may later be reversed or eliminated, but is a crucial part of the process. Sometimes you just need to get things a bit cleaner so you can start to wrap your head around it, even if those changes are later factored out.